# Stealing inside the move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, move-semantics, move-constructor

During the implementation of the move constructor of a toy class, I noticed a pattern:

```
array2D(array2D&& that)
{
    data_ = that.data_;
    that.data_ = 0;

    height_ = that.height_;
    that.height_ = 0;

    width_ = that.width_;
    that.width_ = 0;

    size_ = that.size_;
    that.size_ = 0;
}
```

The pattern obviously being:

```
    member = that.member;
    that.member = 0;
```

So I wrote a preprocessor macro to make stealing less verbose and error-prone:

```
#define STEAL(member) member = that.member; that.member = 0;
```

Now the implementation looks as following:

```
array2D(array2D&& that)
{
    STEAL(data_);
    STEAL(height_);
    STEAL(width_);
    STEAL(size_);
}
```

Are there any downsides to this? Is there a cleaner solution that does not require the preprocessor?

Comment: It's *pilfer*, not *steal*. :-)

Comment: I'm not into C++0x programming yet, but it seems to me that the copying work should be done by constructor, perhaps of a POD *state object*, then just clear that whole state object or otherwise in some way set zombie or default state for "other"?

Comment: @Alf: Is that an established term? In that case, I'll consider renaming it.

Comment: @FredOverflow: I don't know about how established, but it's the term that was very often bandied about in early discussions about move semantics.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "steal" was the term used by the MSVC team. It works.

Comment: Why would you need to make sure `that` is left with zeroed values?

Comment: @sbi: Because in my specific case, the destructor will get confused if zombie objects are not completely zeroed out. Of course I could just say `if (data) { ... }` inside the destructor, hm...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the recommended pattern:

```
array2D(array2D&& that)
    : data_(std::move(that.data_)),
      height_(std::move(that.height_)),
      width_(std::move(that.width_)),
      size_(std::move(that.size_))
{
    that.data_ = 0;
    that.height_ = 0;
    that.width_ = 0;
    that.size_ = 0;
}
```

Naturally if the data members are scalar types, the `std::move` isn't needed.  But if you're copying this pattern around, it is helpful to include the `move` anyway so that when the member data aren't scalar, the `std::move` doesn't get forgotten.

Also if the member data have actual move constructors, then you can simply omit the body:

```
array2D(array2D&& that)
    : data_(std::move(that.data_)),
      height_(std::move(that.height_)),
      width_(std::move(that.width_)),
      size_(std::move(that.size_))
{
}
```

And if you want to generalize to types that don't have move constructors, but do have a resource-less default constructed state, you can:

```
array2D(array2D&& that)
    : data_(std::move(that.data_)),
      height_(std::move(that.height_)),
      width_(std::move(that.width_)),
      size_(std::move(that.size_))
{
    that.data_ = Data();
    that.height_ = Height();
    that.width_ = Width();
    that.size_ = Size();
}
```

I recommend ordering these statements in the same order they are declared as data members in the `array2D` class definition.  And I find nothing wrong with the repetition of the initializer list in the body.  It *is* a necessary and second step.  There is no need to sweep it under the rug.

Answer (score 9):

How about using `template`:

```
template<typename T> inline
void MOVE(T &dst, T &src)
{
  dst = src;
  src = 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
MOVE(data_, that.data_);
```

@Fred, from your comment, if you want to avoid mentioning data member twice, then:

```
#define STEAL(X) MOVE(X, that.X)
```

Usage:

```
STEAL(data_);
```

Comment: what about a `template <...> inline void MOVE`?

Comment: @FredOverflow, mentioning twice should be ok, because argument name `that` might be renamed in future. I have edited the answer though for that case also.

Comment: Naming a macro `_MOVE` is not a good idea, because identifiers starting with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Naming a macro `MOVE__` is not a good idea, because identifiers containing two consecutive underscores are reserved for the implementation. (SCNR)

Comment: Naming a function `MOVE` is a bad idea because identifiers in all-uppercase are commonly used for macros. Just name the macro `MOVE()` and the function `move()`.

Answer (score 5):

Initialize your own members to default, and then `swap`.

```
array2D(array2D&& that)
{
    data_ = 0;    
    height_ = 0;    
    width_ = 0;    
    size_ = 0;

    this->swap(that);
}
```

Even cleaner (if your compiler supports it)

```
array2D(array2D&& that)
: array2D() {
    this->swap(that);
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but wouldn't it be sort of inefficient?

Comment: This won't work without a specialized `swap` because the C++0x `std::swap` moves things around, leading to an infinite recursion...

Comment: @Alf: The compiler can easily handle this. @Johannes: I explicitly called a member function, not `std::swap`. Offering a swap operation is the best way to do many semantics, including copying, so it's not unreasonable to expect one to have been provided- even move-only classes are swappable.

Comment: If you do this, why not delegating to the default constructor?

Comment: Oh, very nice! Could I also replace the assignments with `memset`? Just kidding ;)

Comment: @sbi: I chose not to delegate to the default constructor because as far as I know, no compilers support it. However, it would definitely be cleaner.

Comment: @DeadMG: Ah, I didn't know that constructor delegation wasn't supported yet. Too bad, it seems one of the easier features.

Comment: @sbi: I believe that it's not so much about the feature being easy as having a relatively limited use case. The Visual Studio team, for example, picked rvalue refs first because everybody benefits hugely. Constructor delegation- sure, it's nice, but a couple library writers not being saved a few extra lines isn't that big a deal. In some cases, you could even use `*this = array2D();`, for example- although, not in the rvalue constructor :P

Comment: @DeadMG: By the way, `array2D` has had a `swap` member function right from the start in order to implement the exception-safe assignment operator via copy-and-swap :)

Comment: @DeadMG: following @JohannesD remark --> to be clear, in C++0x, you should implement either the move constructor OR the swap fully, and you can write the other in term of the one you implemented (unless you'd rather do the work twice...). Although, I do wonder, it seems somewhat best handled by having "automatic" resources.